# Is it possible to apply a TypeScript decorator to all fields in a class?

Tags: typescript

I've been fiddling with decorators in Typescript and I have a simple problem, suppose I have a custom decorator called `RetainType` and a class like this:

```
class Person {
    @RetainType name: string;
    @RetainType age: number;
    @RetainType dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

I'd like to be able to write:

```
@RetainType class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

In other words, is there any way to apply a decorator to all properties in a class? I use `@RetainType` to emit metadata about the individual properties (design:type specifically). It would be nice to have a more concise way of doing this than annotating all the fields one by one.

Comment: What does `RetainType` do? Can you add the code for that?

Comment: Literally nothing, it's an empty decorator, I'm just using it to force the TypeScript compiler to generate design:type metadata (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

Comment: No, you won't be able to do that with a class decorator as the properties won't be accisible from the class constructor when the decorator function is called. You can add `@Reflect.metadata("design:type", PROPERTY_TYPE)` to each property and then with a class decorator use those somehow but I don't see how that's better than to use your `RetainType` decorator.

Comment: I am also looking for a similar feature in TypeScript where you can force a TypeScript to generate meta data for all properties in a Class.

Answer (score 1):

Property decorator is applied to one property. It returns nothing, just do some stuff with related property.

Class decorator is applied to class constructor. So it should return function that substitutes normal constructor with some functionality.

In class decorating function you can do anything - even enumerating all class properties with decorating them in expected manner. So you can do what you want if write extra code. But you can't use property decorators as class decorators without changing them. It just wouldn't work.

Comment: So you're saying I CAN add property decorators in a class decorator? Could you provide a short example of this please?

Comment: And again: `you can do what you want if write extra code. But you _can't_ use property decorators as class decorators without changing them`

So answering your question: write **class** decorator that enumerates all class properties and changes them respectively.

Comment: The problem is that there is no change to the property itself, the decorator I have on the property is completely empty. Its only purpose is to force the typescript compiler to generate metadata (see `emitDecoratorMetadata` compiler option). There is no code in the decorator that does this, it's merely the presence of the decorator that makes the compiler emit the metadata. I figured I'd have to somehow apply the property decorator to all the properties to do this in a class decorator, but I don't know how / if this is even possible.